# Google Play has not yet approved my newest update to my app after 5 days

Tags: android, google-play

I just uploaded the 12th update (APK) for my app 5 days ago and it is still not available in Google Play. Usually it only takes a few hours and it is available. Is there any solution/reason why this might happen? Anyone experienced this before? If yes, what was the problem/solution?

I have contacted Google and are awaiting reply..

**EDIT:**

Finally it is available. It took almost 6 days according to my APK list. No response from Google yet.

Comment: @Alex: That sucks :P My latest update is a very minor fix that does not add any new functionality (plain GUI adjustment). I also do not have any ads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After six days it got published. Still awaiting response from Google to know why it was delayed so long.

**Edit:**
Google said something like: "There might be many reasons for why an app is not published within 24 hours and it might take a while sometimes."

Answer (score 0):

There's no manual approval process in Google Play. The only think that

1. your app cannot be found is that it is not compatible with device
   you are trying to look for it on,
2. you in fact did not push it for release (check Google Play console)
3. Google servers may need some time to propagate (but usually it takes up to 24 hrs from my experience).

You basically cannot do much about case "3".

Comment: There is now some sort of review process http://android-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2015/03/creating-better-user-experiences-on.html

Comment: It's compatible with all of my 3 Android devices (by both testing and from the compatibility list). It's pushed for release, like every other timer. It has been way more than 24 hours. I guess I'll have to wait until Google answers. It happened after they enabled "open-beta-testing", but not be the reason, but it is suspect.

Comment: @tyczj for it it was automatic (I mean age rating), Perhaps there are some automatic tests that may raise some alarms and if so, someone may take a look at your app, but seeing how much crap is in Google Play I really doubt it works.

Comment: @tyczj: Thanks for the info. I have had the "Update pending" for 4 days. This really sucks.

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski: Both 1. and 2. is something you can actually do something about.

Comment: True. Corrected. Thanks

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski: Is it? :P